# How to sum third position in arrays?

Tags: ruby

I have a record with arrays:

```
@arrays = ["41,3,4", "39,2,3"]
```

I want to sum the third position of each of the arrays together (4+3)

I tried:

```
@arrays.sum[3]
```

Do I need to iterate the array first?

Thanks!

Comment: those are strings inside the array, you need to split(",") them so they become an array. And then why wouldn't you simply add the 3rd element ? arr1[2] + arr2[2]

Comment: `@arrays` (plural) is a misnomer – you only have _one_ array.

Comment: _record_ is not a concept known to Ruby. Please specify more precisely, what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

You can give [`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) a block to tell it what to add up:

```
arrays.sum { |e| e.split(',')[2].to_i }
```

Comment: Oh, hey, `sum` comes with a built-in `map` argument. That's a neat shorthand!

Comment: Insignificant in his case, but if each string were longer it might create a performance issue: tell `#split` to only split 3 times. `arrays.sum { |e| e.split(',', 3)[2].to_i }`

Answer (score 1):

split elements by `,`, grab 3rd, convert it to integer, then sum.

```
arrays.inject(0) { |acc, triplet| acc += triplet.split(/,/)[2].to_i; acc }
```

Comment: Not very pretty but worked!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use `{ |acc, triplet| acc + triplet.split(/,/)[2].to_i }` as the block and avoid the `;`

Comment: For another esoteric answer: `arrays.each_with_object([0]) { |x, acc| acc[0] += x.split(/,/, 3)[2].to_i }.first`

Comment: @Chris Or fake a pointer with a hash: `arrays.each_with_object({ sum: 0 }) { |x, acc| acc[:sum] += x.split(/,/, 3)[2].to_i }[:sum]`

Comment: thanks to @muistooshort's trick, `arrays.inject(0) {|acc, triplet|  acc += triplet[/\,(\d+)$/, 1].to_i }` also works

Comment: It works because `acc += ...` returns the result of that operation, but the mutation of `acc` is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: i meant `acc + triplet` actually, not mutating it.  a typo while copying and pasting -))